# PHP creating slugify (clean URL) links in simple way?

Tags: php, url

I think this is the simplest way to slugify urls. You have any contra-indication?

```php
function url_clean($str){
        $str = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $str);
        $clean_str = preg_replace(array('/\'|\"/','/ /'),array('','-'),$str);
        return $clean_str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, simpler way to code your solution is to use the `strtr` function which "translates characters". Also I made sure to escape the special characters in the regex.

```
function url_clean($str) {
    $accent = array(' űáéúőóüöíŰÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ');
    $clean  = array('-uaeuoouoiUAEUOOUOI');
    $str = strtr($str, $accent, $clean);
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/', '', $str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your otherwise elegant approach:

1. `iconv` silently cuts the string if a disallowed UTF-8 character is present. The solution would be to add `//IGNORE` to the `iconv()` call but 1/ a bug in glibc seems to prevent this 2/ PHP developers don't seem to want to implement a work-around. An [option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#108643) is to remove invalid characters yourself:

   ```
   ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none"); 
   $text= mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
   ```
2. You're not removing all characters that are present in ASCII but disallowed in a URL: [see this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/481584).